# How to remove user "PostgreSQL" in Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: postgresql, user-management

I uninstalled PostgreSQL with `sudo apt-get --purge remove` and did the same for all the packages but when I go to login there's still a "PostgreSQL" user. I tried running `sudo deluser PostgreSQL` but all I get is

```
/usr/sbin/deluser: The user `PostgreSQL' does not exist.
```

How do I completely remove this user account after uninstalling PostgreSQL?

Edit: Just realized there are leftover files in `/opt/PostgreSQL/9.6/` that haven't been removed. Could this be the cause? I'm not super familiar with this area of the file system.

Edit 2: I found a few running processes owned by "postgres": which is weird because I thought I completely uninstalled it.

Edit 3: `cat /etc/passwd` contains: `postgres:x:1001:1001:PostgreSQL:/opt/PostgreSQL/9.6:`

Comment: Where exactly do you see this user?

Comment: When I first boot up Ubuntu, at the login screen there's my user account that's always been there and below that is a "PostgreSQL" account.

Comment: Are you sure the name is not postgres?  Did you remove all of the databases created with postgresql?  They are probably still around, but if you remove postgres, they will not have an official user.

Comment: It's definitely named PostgreSQL. I never did anything beyond installing PostgreSQL so I'm not sure if there are any databases leftover or how to find them if there are. I just removed postgres and all it's related packages.

Comment: Could you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/963743/edit) and post the content of your `/etc/passwd` file please?

Comment: Okay I posted the edit containing the postgres passwd info

Comment: Stuff  in `/opt` is optional software not provided by mainstream packages. Presumably your postgresql install comes an EntrepriseDB package rather than Ubuntu or PGDG. See [How to completely remove EnterpriseDB Installation of Postgresql on Ubuntu?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51153) on DBA.se

Answer (score 2):

People says that isnt ans answer xD

> *can u give us the output of this?
>       cat /etc/passwd | grep -i postgre*

Edited and reformulated

```
cat /etc/passwd | grep -i postgre
postgres:x:111:118:PostgreSQL administrator,,,:/var/lib/postgresql:/bin/bash
```

Login Name and User Name are not the same the graphical login tool its showing you the Login Name. Try:

```
sudo deluser postgres
```

Also read

```
man 5 passwd
```

Comment: Running deluser on postgres returns a warning because it's being used by a process. I don't understand how a process could be using it if I "uninstalled" postgresql unless I did it incorrectly.

Comment: $ sudo ps -ef | grep "postgres" will help u to understand what is happening

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled postgreSQL using `sudo apt-get --purge remove postgresql`, but a previous user I created still remained. Then, I used `sudo dropuser <username>` and it worked. I hope this is useful.